# Need to access mData nested value in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Below is my api response,

```
{ "aaData":{"req":[{"requests":"132"}]}}
```

Need to show requests value in jquery datatable below is my code,

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "aTargets": [0],
            "mData":"req[0].requests",
        },
```

but above code not working,but if change api reponse to below,

```
{ "aaData":{"req":"132"}}
"aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "aTargets": [0],
                "mData":"req",
            },
```

above code working.....How can I access the requests value from this kind of response `{ "aaData":{"req":[{"requests":"132"}]}}` , Anyhelp appreciated..

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/wLd44p3b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is `data.aaData.req` :

```
aaData: data.aaData.req,
aoColumnDefs: [{
  aTargets: [0],
  mData: 'requests',
  sTitle: 'requests'
}]
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/973/** because there is no other options. The only suitable datasource is the `req` item, since it is an array of objects.

However, if you actually wanted an `aaData` datasource with nested childs, then your JSON should look like this :

```
var data = { "aaData":[
   { "req":[{"requests":"132"}]} },
   { "req":[{"requests":"133"}]} }
]};
```

`aaData` as an array of objects, then use dot notation for child objects or array indexes :

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
  aaData: data.aaData,
  aoColumnDefs: [{
    aTargets: [0],
    mData: 'req.0.requests',
    sTitle: 'requests'
  }]  
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/974/**

Answer (score -1):

According to dataTable's doc: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html

I think you should try testing like; (haven't test it yet)

```
    "aoColumnDefs": [
    {
        "aTargets": [0],
        "mData":"req.requests",
    },
```

Comment: did you use { "aaData":{"req":[{"requests":"132"}]}} or { "aaData":req}?

Answer (score -2):

If I understood correctly then you can turn to request

`responseBody.aaData.req[0].requests`

Answer (score -3):

You can try as follows

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    {
        "aTargets": [0],
        "mData":"req[0]["requests"],
    }
```

instead of

```
   "aoColumnDefs": [
    {
        "aTargets": [0],
        "mData":"req[0].requests",
    },
```

Comment: what do you think is different from both codes you placed above, ways to read from an object is either `object.key` or `object["key"]`.

Comment: if your property name is not  a valid identifier you can use [propertyname] notation to get the property value

Comment: ` "mData":"req[0].requests",` and `"mData":"req[0].requests",` whats the difference